# Armature and Mesh not working together as intended

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I'm new to blender and trying to rig a model for animation later. I have made the model, and attached bones to the mesh. However, for some reason, the bones that control the right side of the mesh (right arm and legs) don't do anything, but the left side bones work but what they do is mirrored.
[image]

[image]

Comment: could you share your file? for example on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Did you applied Rot & Scale (CTRL+A+Apply Rot & Scale, in object mode) on your model before any skinning or rigging process? That could be the reason you are seing distorted mesh.

Comment: If you have a mirror modifier it should be on top of the modifier stack

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can check and try to help you?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think I know how to fix. I still have the mirror modifier on the mesh, as in I haven't applied it. Would that be the issue?

Comment: Yep, it was because I didn't apply the mirror modifier before adding the armature. Oops